# compiler giving error on forward struct declaration

Tags: c++, struct

I have a code like this where i cannot put "struct node" above "struct mnode"
So i declared it on the top, as shown below.
But the compiler says the field n has incomplete type.
How to correctly declare a struct on the top??

```
struct node;
struct mnode{
    int j;
    node n;
};
struct node{
    int k;
};
```

Comment: You have to put the `node` definition above the `mnode` one. There's no way around that if you want `mnode` to hold a `node` instance.

Answer (score 5):

For a class-type class member, you need a definition. A declaration won't do. So in this case, the full definition of `node` has to come before `mnode`.

Forward declarations only work when the full definition isn't required - pointer or reference members, return types or method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `node` is ... well incomplete. You cannot have fields of incomplete types in a struct/class definition. But you can have a pointer to node because the size of a pointer is known:

```
struct node;
struct mnode{
    int j;
    node* n;
};
struct node{
    int k;
};
```

Comment: You can also use references from forward declarations (`node&` (though I'd only use this for function definitions) and smart ptrs (`std::unique_ptr<node>`).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains because it needs to know a few things about `mnode` for which it needs more information about `node`. First, it needs to know the size of a `mnode` object in order to be able to construct it, but for that it needs to know the size of a `node`. It also needs to know how to generate the following functions:

- default constructor
- destructor
- copy and move constructors
- copy and move assignment operators

And for that it needs the corresponding functions in `node`. I may be forgetting something else, but you can see that it needs the full definition of `node` for quite a lot of things. So no, an advance declaration will not do.

If you cannot provide the full definition of `node` for whatever reason, you can resort to changing the type of `n` to, for instance, a `node*`. The compiler has all that information for a pointer, so no problem there.